# why css opacity property is not working on the clicked image

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm displaying some images while clicking on the images those image will display
i want whenever i click on any image so those image should set opacity property because to know this image been clicked.
but only first time it is working not the second time.
here is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style type="text/css">
      .active{
      opacity: 0.7;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>
      <script type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div id="main_img">
         <img id="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" onchange="q()">
      </div>
      <div id="thumb_img">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  onclick='changeImage(this)' style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" id="first">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  onclick='changeImage(this)'style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" id="first">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  onclick='changeImage(this)'style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" id="first">
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var sr
         function changeImage(obj){
           
           sr = $(obj).attr('src');
           /*alert(sr);*/
           $('#img').attr('src',sr);
            /*$('#img').removeClass('active');*/
           $("#first").addClass('active');    
         }
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

as you seen on the clicking of the second row first image only set as opacity
i want to set opacity on any image of second row which is has been clicked

Comment: That's because you're duplicating your IDs. IDs must be unique in a document.

Comment: i had tried to set unique id but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Updated code. Keep in mind that class active is added once and will be in DOM unless you will remove it. 
becasue you are using onclick and passing this inside it, you handler should use passed object like this `$(obj).addClass('active');`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <style type="text/css">
      .active{
      opacity: 0.7;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <h2 style="text-align:center">Lightbox</h2>
      <script type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div id="main_img">
         <img onclick='changeImage(this)' id="img" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" onchange="q()">
      </div>
      <div id="thumb_img">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  onclick='changeImage(this)' style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" id="first">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  onclick='changeImage(this)'style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" id="first">
         <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"  onclick='changeImage(this)'style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" id="first">
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         var sr
         function changeImage(obj){
           
           sr = $(obj).attr('src');
           /*alert(sr);*/
           $(obj).attr('src',sr);
            /*$('#img').removeClass('active');*/
           $(obj).addClass('active'); 
            $(obj).siblings().removeClass('active');
         }
         
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it is nice bro but whenever selecting other one then first selected should be get free from opacity. each of click they should work.

Comment: See my updated code, this is something you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using the id selector. An id can only be on the page once, so the browser takes the first element with the id and ignores all other ones. If you want to target multiple Elements you need to add a class (and also a class selector) like so:

```
<img class="img-changed" [...] >
<img class="img-changed" [...] >

$(".img-changed").addClass("active");
```

Comment: thanks for replaying bro. but i want to set opacity on the clicked image if i clicked on second image then first image which is clicked before should be get free of opacity

Answer (score -1):

This also works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var sr
     function changeImage(obj){

       sr = $(obj).attr('src');
       $(obj).attr('src',sr);
       $(obj).addClass('active'); 
       $('#thumb_img').children().not(obj).removeClass('active'); //we can use not method
     }

</script>
```